# How can I use a Button for multiple actions in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, button

I have an eCommerce app and by clicking on confirm order button, I need a notification to be displayed & place an order as well & also for sending a mail to the customer. I have done it but don't know whether it's valid or not. Can anyone help in this matter? I will share the code below.

public class confirmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText nameEditText, phoneEditText,emailEditText, addressEditText, cityEditText;
private Button confirmOrderbtn;
private String totalAmount = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm);
    totalAmount = getIntent().getStringExtra("Total Price");

    confirmOrderbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_final_order_btn);
    nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shipment_name);
    phoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shipment_phone);
    emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shipment_email);
    addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shipment_address);
    cityEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shipment_city);

    confirmOrderbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check();


        }
    });


}




private void check() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEditText.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide your full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneEditText.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide your Phone number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEditText.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide your Email id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(addressEditText.getText().toString()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide your Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cityEditText.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide your city", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ConfirmOrder();
        addNotification();
    }

}
private void addNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bell) //set icon for notification
                    .setContentTitle("Order Placed") //set title of notification
                    .setContentText("Thank you")//this is notification message
                    .setAutoCancel(true) // makes auto cancel of notification
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT); //set priority of notification


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //notification message will get at NotificationView
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", "Thank you");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}


private void ConfirmOrder() {
    final String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;
    Calendar CallForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(CallForDate.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentDate.format(CallForDate.getTime());

    final DatabaseReference ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders")
            .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone());
    HashMap<String, Object> ordersMap = new HashMap<>();
    ordersMap.put("totalAmount", totalAmount);
    ordersMap.put("name", nameEditText.getText().toString());
    ordersMap.put("phone", phoneEditText.getText().toString());
    ordersMap.put("email", emailEditText.getText().toString());
    ordersMap.put("address", addressEditText.getText().toString());
    ordersMap.put("city", cityEditText.getText().toString());
    ordersMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
    ordersMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
    ordersMap.put("state", "not shipped");
    ordersRef.updateChildren(ordersMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                        child("Cart List")
                        .child("User View")
                        .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                        .removeValue()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(confirmActivity.this, "Your final order has been succesfully placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(confirmActivity.this, HomeActivity2.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I would say move the `addNotification` in the success of your firebase entry that way you are really confirmed that it got executed, else it can be false positive.

Comment: Thank you so much , its executing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Move `addNotification();` in  `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` of `onComplete` of your firebase, that way you are only sure that order is really done else it may stuck in some firebase error as well and customer will get the "Order placed" notification which will be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I thought of adding , just for testing it I added it there .Thank you so much will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a boolean global variable first to check a successful order.

```
private boolean isOrderConfirmed = false; <-- This one.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
```

And, set that variable in `onComplete()` method.

```
 @Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    isOrderConfirmed = false; //Reset <-- This one
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    ...
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                isOrderConfirmed = true; //<-- And this one.
                Toast.makeText(confirmActivity.this, "Your final order has been succesfully placed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
...
```

Then, you can use that variable to do something.

```
private void check() {
...
} else {
    ConfirmOrder();
    if(isOrderConfirmed) {
        addNotification(); <-- This one.
        // doSomething();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah its actually interesting one , will work on it. Thank you so much.